# Dual major in mathematics and physics

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, major

I am doing dual major in mathematics and physics and I want to pursue my future study in theoretical physics, I mean want to do PhD in it.
Although, I am dual majoring but my university provides only single transcript for both major, and I have got good grades (9.4/10) in physics but bad in maths, thus overall grade is 7.8/10.
My question:
While applying for graduate admission, which grade should I put in the application?
The overall grade or physics grade?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: I have seen that graduate school applications in the US often ask for overall grade and major grade separately. Not sure if it would help for a double major though.

Comment: Bad in maths and pursuing theoretical physics? ok, Maxwell was not the brightest mathematician in the room, but still ... did you properly assess your capabilities vs your expectations?

ps: maybe it was Rutherford and not Maxwell, my apologies

Comment: @EarlyGrey I am very confident about my learning and I am not even very bad at maths if get little more time than those "two hours" in the exam or it might also be the case that I am not suitable such "system". Also most of the professor who took our maths courses are Algebraic Geometer and while delivering lecture they sometimes forget the level of the course,which gives not only headache to "us" but most of the maths olympiad medelist.

Comment: Then you can leave a comment (where? I do not know :) ) that math courses are ranked absolutely and not relatively, so that having a grade of 70% the maximum is actually what is achieved by the best x%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that nearly every university would require your grade as represented in your transcript - your overall grade. If you hide that, then you could be accused of misconduct.

However, you can, in other materials, point out that your physics grades are higher and report it. There is no problem with that. Perhaps a simple phrase in a sentence in the SoP would serve.

Being "selective" permits all sorts of potential abuse.

Comment: This is really what I wanted. Thanks @Buffy.